# migrating from EF to stored procs

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

We created a prototype to our Web store in MVC 3 and EF (4.1 I think). The EF model was created

Turns out our CTO wants all production SQL executed with stored procedures to avoid exposing table names and fields.

Does anyone have advice on how I can introduce stored procedures with minimal disturbance to my C# / EF code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import them into the EDMX model, as function imports, and use the mapping functions to map them to Insert/Update/Delete of the entities.

If you have any custom behaviour in stored procedures, you can execute the SP using `ExecuteFunction`

You shouldn't have too much disruption above the Entity layer, but be aware that EF is quite inflexible in what parameters it wants Stored Procedures defined with

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896231.aspx

Comment: I understand importing SPs to the EDMX. Where I get confused is how i would map them behaviorally? Or would I have to replace all Entity-Object calls with ExecuteFunction calls manually?

Comment: You map the insert,update,delete directly to the entities in the EDMX. For the select, you map the results of a SP to that entity, and call that function on your context to produce a list of results. See http://weblogs.asp.net/dotnetstories/archive/2011/03/01/using-stored-procedures-with-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-application.aspx for exaples.

Comment: I'm beginning to understand. I have to go back to the docs, but this helps a lot. Thanks!